# Is there a way to load functions in zsh on demand?

Tags: function, zsh, autoload

## What I'm trying to do

Sometimes, the commands one has to use to run scripts in a project are very long. I would prefer to be able to use a zsh function with parameters. For example, this command to add a new component in an NX project:

```
npx nx g component todos --project=ui --export
```

I would rather be able to use a zsh function like this:

```
addComponent todos ui
```

I've been reading about how to add functions to be automatically loaded when a zsh terminal starts, but that's not what I want to do. This function only makes sense for this project, I don't want its definition to load everytime a zsh terminal is booted, only when I cd into the project.

What I'd like is to have something like a `.zshfn` file in my project and create my custom functions there. When I `cd` into the project folder, I want zsh to detect that file and automatically load the functions defined there so that I can use them.

## What I have tried to do

I have added this bit to my `.zshrc`:

```
# Autoload functions when changing pwd
load-functions() {
  if [ -f .zshfn ]; then
    read -r fns<.zshfn
    fpath=($pwd $fpath)
    echo "Autoloading functions: ${fns:1}"
    autoload ${fns:1}
  fi
}
add-zsh-hook chpwd load-functions
```

And this is the content of that `.zshfn` file:

```
#hello
hello() {
    print "Hello World"
}
```

And this is the result when I `cd` into a folder with a `.zshfn` file:

[image: result in terminal]

It appears to work, but it really doesn't. There is no error in the execution of the part that's supposed to load the functions, only when trying to use the function that hasn't been loaded.

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to do autoloading here? Wouldn't it be easier to simply define the function `addComponent` inside your .zshrc?

Comment: Do you realize that `autoload` _lazy loads_ functions on demand? When you autoload a function, it’s not actually loaded into memory until you try to use it.

Comment: But if you want a command that’s only available when you are in a particular dir, why don’t you just put an executable script in that dir?